# Showing the restriction of the quotient map in the construction of an attachment space is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Also suppose $A\subseteq Y$ and $f:A\rightarrow X$ is continous.
If $q:X+Y \rightarrow X+_f Y $ is the natural projection from the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$ onto the attachment space.

In Stephen Willard's General Topology, the following is claimed:

The restriction of $q$ to $Y$ is a homeomorphism.

However, this is clearly not true since the restriction is not injective. For example suppose $a,b$ are distinct elements of $A$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$. Then $q$ sends $a$ and $b$ to the same element in the attachment space since we identify $x$ with $a$ and $b$ and so $q(a) = q(b)$.

Am I correct or am I misunderstanding the attachment space construction?

Here is the exact extract from the book,
[image]

Comment: Points in $A_p$ are identified, no?  $a,b \in A_{f(b)}$

Comment: Say that those $a,b$ are the only points mapping to some $x$ through $f$. Then in the decomposition space we would have $\{x,a,b\}$ as a point and both $a$ and $b$ are sent there via $q$? I think I am misunderstanding the construction maybe?

Comment: But they're not in $Y$.

Comment: They are? They are in $A$ and $A$ is a subset of $Y$.

Comment: $A$ is a subset of $X$.

Comment: Oh I misread that one... Thanks :) I first read the definition on wikipedia and the notation is subtly different.